# Multiple view models with MahApps.Metro within TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to get a TabControl to displays holding data from two different categories/viewmodels. Based on these two resources, [WPF MahApps.Metro Tabcontrol data bound?](//stackoverflow.com/a/12285779/1548472) and [DataTemplates aren't applied](//social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8f20b8fd-19c3-4881-b530-d3a99cc9f1a5/datatemplates-arent-applied?forum=wpf), I tried the following which doesn't quite make the cut as it gives an compilation error.

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:SubViewModelAlpha}">
            <TextBlock>SubViewModelAlpha</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:SubViewModelBeta}">
            <TextBlock>SubViewModelBeta</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

I have the corresponding classes:

```
public class ViewModel { 
   public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class SubViewModelAlpha : ViewModel { }
public class SubViewModelBeta : ViewModel { }

// In another class, I have this property ... 
public ObservableColletion<ViewModel> Collection {
   get { return _collection; } 
}
// ... and this list
private ObservableColletion<ViewModel> _collection;
```

The error I get is "Property ContentTemplate is set more than once", which kind of make sense, but how can I apply the same type of checking against a type of ViewModel before setting the ContentTemplate stuff?

I have already tried using the `DataType` on the ContentTemplate but that doesn't work.

PS! I do of course want much more data within each viewmodel, but this example shows the gist of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading some more, it seems like the issue can be solved using a ContentTemplateSelector, albeit I'm not sure if there are any strange dependcies going on.

I changed my xaml to look like:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
            ContentTemplateSelector="{DynamicResource MyContentTemplateSelector}">
    <TabControl.Resource>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="BetaTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewModels:SubViewModelAlpha}">
            <TextBlock>SubViewModelAlpha</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="BetaTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewModels:SubViewModelBeta}">
            <TextBlock>SubViewModelBeta</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <viewModels:MyContentTemplateSelector
            x:Key="MyContentTemplateSelector" 
            AlphaTemplate="{StaticResource AlphaTemplate}"
            BetaTemplate="{StaticResource BetaTemplate}" />
    <TabControl.Resource>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

With the following class added to my project:

```
public class MyContentTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate AlphaTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate BetaTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is SubViewModelAlpha) 
            return AlphaTemplate;

        if (item is SubViewModelBeta)
            return BetaTemplate;

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

This code is loosely based on [Using ContentTemplateSelector](https://zamjad.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/using-contenttemplateselector/), and I'm not sure what kind of caveats there are, if any.

I do however believe an even nicer solution directly using the data type is availabe, but I don't know how! Yet...

Answer (score 1):

the problem here i think is that the content template it self doesn't accept more than a single template
, it's like when you add two grids for a single window it will tell you that the content property can't be set more than once

what i can think of here from a basic prospective is that you can do a single template that combines both template and choose between them by triggers and converters

## Edit

check this article 
http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector

Comment: I know,  and that is why I ask how to differentiate based on the type of the item source

Comment: How?  That tenplate needs to refer to two different viewModels?

Comment: if you want me to go deeper then why do you need 2 data templates ? why is a single template bad ?

Comment: One of the templates is just five values, and the other holds some other values as well as a list of other values. Hard to contemplate these within the same template

Comment: i added an article about template selector in the answer